# how to wait until page redirect finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a redirect, then perform additional operations on the markup of the new page. How can I make sure that the additional stuff I want wait until the redirect is **finished**?

```
window.location.replace(url);
//call additional stuff here
```

I'm hoping for something that's more reliable than just waiting by x number of seconds.

Comment: You will have to add the javascript in the new page that is loaded. After a page is redirected it will not finish the rest of the javascript because that page is now gone.

Comment: You may have to use ajax instead rather then page redirection.

Comment: @ahgood, I need to do a page redirect, because I don't want the user on this page anymore.

Comment: @Stephan Muller, so is there a way I could (before doing the redirect) at least activate a boolean flag or even edit the js file so that it knows that it needs to run a certain function after it loads the new page.

Comment: You can add a parameter in the url (?flag=true) but you would probably have to use php to have the new page read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional javascript code you want to execute after redirecting to the next page (redirected `url`) will be done by javascript on the redirected page and not from the previous one where you are redirecting from. There is no callback for redirecting.